# Trying to create a nested object. What is the clean coding practice for it?

Tags: c#, json, clean-architecture

I have a JSON structure and tried to create a relevant c# object for it.

There are 4 nested objects.

It looks like this:

```
    public class One{
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public One(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public int A { get => a; }
    public int B { get => b; }
}

public class Two{ 
    private int c;
    private One one;

    public Two(int c, One one)
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
    public int C { get => c; }
    public One one { get => d; }
}
public class Three {
    private int e;
    private List<Two> twos;

    public Three(int e, List<Two> twos)
    {
        this.e = e;
        this.twos = twos;
    }
    public int E { get => e; }
    public List<Two> twos { get => twos; }
}

public class CollectionOfObjects{
    private List<Three> collection;
    public CollectionOfObjects(List<Three> collection)
    {
        this.collection = collection;
    }
    public List<Three> Collection {get => this.collection;}
}
```

In order to create CollectionOfObjects, first I need to create class One, then Two and then Three.

I want my code to look clean. Which approach is better; Should I just call one constructor and pass all the parameters necessary to create all 4 objects, or should I manually create the One, Two, Three and CollectionOfObjects?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. A, B, and C have the exact same structure. An object with 2 numeric values. There is no nesting currently. Nesting would be an object A including B, and B including C.
What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Hazrelle my bad. Edited code accordingly

Comment: This can be a somewhat opinionated. One coder's 'clean' code can be another coder's spaghetti nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest object construction as shown below. But if the structure is simple as this one and fixed, I would go with `json` by example that would deserialize quickly such structure.

```
            var data = new CollectionOfObjects(
                new List<Three>()
                {
                    new Three(3, new List<Two>()
                    {
                        new Two(2, new One(1, 1)),
                        new Two(3, new One(2, 2))
                    }),
                    new Three(4, new List<Two>()
                    {
                        new Two(2, new One(1, 1)),
                        new Two(3, new One(2, 2))
                    })
                }
            );
```